# In generic how convert one type data to another type data

Tags: c#, generics

Work on C#,In generic as doesn't work with value types (like int),Want a extension method for all datatype like:int,long,string.conversion method is bellow

```
public static T Translate<T>(this T inputNumber) where T : class
{
    return inputNumber.ToString()
        .Replace("１", "1")
        .Replace("２", "2")
        .Replace("３", "3")
        .Replace("４", "4")
        .Replace("５", "5")
        .Replace("６", "6")
        .Replace("７", "7")
        .Replace("８", "8")
        .Replace("９", "9")
        .Replace("０", "0") as T;
}    

var result= 2.Translate<longTypeData>();
```

want a **long** type data in result variable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter they seem to be different unicode characters

Comment: @ René Vogt,you are right.

Comment: I don't think it's possible since you cannot use `as T` without `class` constraint.

Comment: there is no common base-class for the built-in value-types like int, decimal... because they don´t share any common logic. An integer is totally different from a double. Thus you´re stuck on writing your method for all the possible types again and again (but you may re-dreict the calls of course to one single method).

Comment: Yeah it's [FullWidth Digit 9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff19/index.htm)

Comment: @Kamo Sure you can, e.g. `where T ; struct`

Comment: `where T : class`? It seems `T` should be `struct` as you want to pass value types, not reference types. But really your question is hard to understand. In the end you try to cast a `string` via `as` into `T`, which should probably be a `long`. That won't work. Can you explain a little clearer what you are trying to achieve? Maybe with help of someone with better English capabilities?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know but then you cannot use `as T` ;)

Comment: @Kamo That won´t work anyway, because you can´t cast `string` to *anything* except `object` so `as T` will *allways*  return `null` (unless `T` is `object`)

Comment: Why not just do `number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` - then it will produce a number that won't need translating to the invariant culture...

Comment: How should *any* numbers `ToString`-representation return a bold `"1"`?

Comment: So I try a guess: You have a string, want to replace those digit characters to be able to convert it either to `int` or `long`. So your method's parameter should be `string` instead of `T`. Then you need to replace the digits, then convert the string to a number, maybe `Convert.ToInt64()` and then cast it to your return value.

Comment: You´re aware that you can just use `long a = 2`? I can´t see any reason for that strange kind of conversion. Apart from this: what should your method do on `var a = 2.2.Translate<int>()`?

Comment: @Kamo,@HimBromBeere,@Matthew Watson thanks for your valuable information, i need to convert one type data to another type data. you some guys tried to guide me another direction, i need it fore some special reason i know there is some build in conversion process in .net , But those process not fulfill my requirement,so i seeking expert suggestion. my problem solve this one line syntax return (T)Convert.ChangeType(convertNumber, typeof(T)); thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do. But if you want this function to use as some kind of converter, I would pass two generic type arguments in:

```
public static T Translate<Q, T>(this Q inputNumber) {
    string value = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Q)).ConvertToString(inputNumber);

    string replacedValue = value.ToString()
        .Replace("１", "1")
        .Replace("２", "2")
        .Replace("３", "3")
        .Replace("４", "4")
        .Replace("５", "5")
        .Replace("６", "6")
        .Replace("７", "7")
        .Replace("８", "8")
        .Replace("９", "9")
        .Replace("０", "0");

    return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(replacedValue);
}
```

Later you can use it like this:

```
int result = "４４４".Translate<string, int>();
```

But keep in mind: *passing invalid type combinations will generate an exception!*

Comment: ,thanks for your valuable information,I tell about this solution in my comment.Thank you.